# How to do custom sort logic in vuetify 3?

Tags: javascript, sorting, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

When I use `:custom-key-sort="customKeySort"` on `v-data-table`, the function gives me 2 values taking the key directly from the object. If the key was `a`, and the 2 objects it is sorting is `{b:1}` and `{b:2}`, I would get `undefined` as the 2 parameters to the sort function. Is there a way to get back the 2 original objects so I can do my own custom sort logic? This would be very useful as I create my own headers, and the values I show in the table are a calculation of some nested properties in the original objects.

Comment: Can you please explain it in more better way ? Right now problem statement is unclear to me.